# Is there an industry term for a letter inquiring if a publisher is interested in a work?

Tags: publishing, first-time-author, manuscripts, traditional-publishing

I finished writing a non-fiction manuscript and now need to find an appropriate publisher. There are no existing books in this particular niche, so it is challenging to find a publisher to fit.

In the past, I sent the manuscript to a publisher, and waited a whole 3 months before they rejected it. Since it is not appropriate to send submissions of non-fiction to multiple publishers simultaneously, I lost time waiting for their reply...

...I'd rather instead send letters to a dozen publishers at once to check if they are interested in reading my manuscript before becoming "locked" into waiting on my submission to be approved or not. Is there an industry term for such a letter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The term you're looking for is "query letter."

Reedsy gives several tips for writing one:
https://blog.reedsy.com/guide/how-to-write-a-query-letter/query-letter-examples/

Comment: To add to this answer: query letters should also be the default way of trying to get an agent/publisher, as many (maybe most?) of them have guidelines explicitly saying to not send full manuscripts unless asked for them.